# Preorder in Virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Does anyone have a "quick and dirty" solution for a preorder-system in virtuemart?
I found only some "strange" websites on the web who are selling their hacks for 50$+

Thanks!
Christian.

Comment: What do you need it to do? VM already supports selling virtual products, which is what a pre-order really is. Why wouldn't you just use a regular VM product you call pre-order?

Comment: Hi @Brent. Haven't found any information about that. Did you mean the "download" section? Do you have a link for me where I can find more information about virtual products?

Comment: Virtual products are basically anything that doesn't require you to ship something to the buyer. It can be a download or file if you want them to print something - http://virtuemart.net/documentation/User_Manual/Product_Files_and_Images.html. For you it would depend on what you want to give the customer so they can redeem their preorder. If they are coming to a store to pick it up, just create a coupon. If you are just shipping something once it is available then treat it as a normal product and leave the order pending until you ship.

Comment: OK. In my case it's a device which should be ready for shipping in about 4 or 5 weeks. Should I only change the "Availability" and set it to 5 weeks?

Comment: Gotcha, now I can answer accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case since you are actually shipping a product, you will want to set it up as you would any other product that you have in stock, then change the Availability option in the product Status tab. You can either type in some text indicating it is a special order that will ship in X period of time, or you can create an image conveying the same information. Upload the image to /components/com_virtuemart/themes/YOUR THEME/images/availability/ so that it appears in the drop down menu.